# Enable Keyboard Input On Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks

I feel like this question is answered by after trying multiple solutions none seem to be working.  I have tried `- (void) ccKeyUp : (NSEvent*) KeyDownEvent
- (void) ccKeyDown : (NSEvent*) KeyDownEvent`

After I this I just use NSLog to output to the console that it has correctly identified to correct key.  However, every time I test it it fails.  C++ has a simple command that allows input from the keyboard to be entered.  Does one exist in Objective-C for Mac programming?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you prefix those methods with `cc`? Do you know what the responder chain is?

Comment: I think it could be cocos2d he's using. If I remember right they use `ccKeyUp` and `ccKeyDown`.